# CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE contains completely other rows than SELECT inside

Tags: mysql

I want to create temporary with some rows inside it to make some operations in procedure after all. The code is quite simple:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_stack ENGINE=MEMORY AS (
    SELECT users.id AS to_user_id, users.rating AS rating, users.lat AS lat, users.lng AS lng

    FROM users USE KEY (generating_stack)

    WHERE
        users.lat BETWEEN 53.8866 AND 54.8286 AND
        users.lng BETWEEN 17.8999 AND 19.3999

    LIMIT 10
);
```

It works, but my tmp_stack table has completely other rows thank the SELECT inside CREATE TEMPORARY query! Just look:

[image]

And the only query inside CREATE TEMPORARY:

[image]

What is going on? I can't use ORDER BY here because it works couple times slower.

Comment: Without ORDER BY, you will get records in “random” order. And by picking only the first 10 out of two different sets of randomly “ordered” records, of course the result can be different each time. _“I can't use ORDER BY here ”_ – you __have to__ if you want consistent results. (If it is “too slow”, check if you have proper indexes set.)

Comment: @CBroe You should add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Records in random order is not problem for me. The question is, why these two SELECT returns completely others results? I can't run these many times and every time the results are the same.

Comment: Ok @CBroe you're right. I've got invalid index so that's why ORDER BY worked really slow. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without ORDER BY, you will get records in “random” order. And by picking only the first 10 out of two different sets of randomly “ordered” records, of course the result can be different each time.

> I can't use ORDER BY here because it works couple times slower.

But you **have to**, if you want consistent results.

(If it is “too slow”, check if you have proper indexes set.)